# Using Angular.js and php to display values from a database rows

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am in the process of building a interface where app info is displayed to the owner. This consists of a table showing stats like:

Who created the channel on the app.

When was it created.

What is the status of the channel.

How many subchannels it contains

and so it goes.

All of the above mentioned data is obtainable from a database and I could easily echo the table data using a `while()` or a `for` loop.

**However**

I would very much like to start implementing and learning `angular`

And how I understand, it is that I would have to create an array of each database field in the row and then, using `array_push`, I would push data in an array for use in JS.

However this would be very time consuming as well as inefficient, which leads me to believe I might be going about it all wrong.

The reason for choosing angular is because I read it is quite easy to sort and filter table data and it seems like a great framework to learn.

So how should I correctly apply angular to my situation to have it work optimally?

Answer (score 0):

Angular consumes only `JSON` so, now you are not going to `echo` the data to create the html output.. instead you need to use PHP to create a `WEB API` responds with `JSON` data when requested.

So, you Angular application will send request to PHP which in turn returns a `JSON` which can be used angular to show the data, apply filter and what not.